How I can take the timediff between timestamps that are in mm:ss.m format in google sheets?
I have the following sheet:

Each time duration is in format of mm:ss.ms how I can calculate the Delta?
Upon image columns are A,B,C,D,E respectively.

Chances are that the values are text strings rather than numeric durations. Use value(), like this:
=value("0:" & C2) - value("0:" & B2)

In the event the values are numeric durations rather than text strings, you can subtract one from the other directly, like this:
=C2 - B2

Format the result as Format > Number > Custom number format > [mm]:ss.000.
See Working with date and time values in Google Sheets
